# How to merge and distribute the first array over the second one in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What would be the elegant way to achieve the result demonstrated in the snippet below.

I'm merging two arrays into a new array by distributing each element of the first array on to the second array.

```
arr1 = ['XYZ', 'ABC']
arr2 = ['EUR', 'USD']
result = ['XYZ/EUR', 'XYZ/USD', 'ABC/EUR', 'ABC/USD']
```

```js
let symbolList = [];
SYMBOLS = ['XYZ', 'ABC']
PAIRS = ['EUR', 'USD']
SYMBOLS.map(s => symbolList.push(PAIRS.map(p => s + '/' + p)));
let processSymbols = symbolList.flat();
console.log(processSymbols)
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's just go ahead and use flatMap :)

```js
const arr1 = ['XYZ', 'ABC']
const arr2 = ['EUR', 'USD']

const result = arr1.flatMap(val => arr2.map(e => `${val}/${e}`))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `reduce()`:

```js
const arr1 = ['XYZ', 'ABC'];
const arr2 = ['EUR', 'USD'];

const result = arr1.reduce((a, c) => {
  arr2.forEach(e => a.push(`${c}/${e}`));  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce an array of arrays and map the parts.

This approach works for more than two arrays as well.

```js
var array1 = ['XYZ', 'ABC'],
    array2 = ['EUR', 'USD'],
    result = [array1, array2].reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(v => b.map(w => `${v}/${w}`)));

console.log(result);
```